# Capture every not ssl connection made to a Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, rds

I am trying to capture every non-ssl connection made to a postgres database. My goal would be to only allow ssl connections to the database but I first want to identify what could possibly break.

I can identify insecure ssl connections using this.

```
select * from pg_stat_ssl 
inner join pg_stat_activity 
on pg_stat_ssl.pid=pg_stat_activity.pid;
```

However, this only captures a point in time of ssl connections to the database, not necessarily every connection ever made to the database.

Is there a way to capture every insecure connection ever made to the database?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to track insecure connections v ssl connections is by turning on `log_connections` in your `postgresql.conf` and then comparing the log output with what’s in `pg_hba.conf`. You’ll need to make sure you know what kinds of connections you allow/disallow—if you allow both ssl and non-ssl connections for a particular host/database/user combination, you may be out of luck.